# Workaround for storing List in DB - any thoughts?

Tags: sql

I'm creating a database for my hockey team storing all kinds of stats. My particular question is about trying to store Games Played by each player.

I'm going into depth with the detail about the stats where I'll be able to refine a search to see what specific games any player has played in (so simply having a general Int for total games played is out of the question - I need to trace back to each game)

I have a Player and Game table (date_of_game is PK for table Game since only one game can be played on a given day, and jerseyNum is PK for table Player since re-using numbers is not allowed even after a player leaves the team), which would be tempting for me just to store a list inside the Game table of who was present during that particular game - but this is bad practice.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to go about storing games played per player?

I thought about making a "WhosPresent" table where I could just use the players and game date as columns and store a "present" or "away" value for each player but then an issue arises where people may leave the team, or new players would be added to the team which would mess up the table columns.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Comment: You do indeed need a GamePlayers table (your WhosPresent table) if you want to follow the rules of normalization and avoid nested tables (your list approach).  You could even extend that to GamePeriodPlayer if you wanted to track which players were playing in which period(s).

Comment: Your GamePlayers table could also have columns GameID, PlayerID, Period1, Period2, Period3 where the period columns could be either true/false or an integer to track minutes-played in each period.

Comment: I agree with Tim, this is classic use case for a mapping table. You may also want to consider an ID for the games, rather than just using the date. If you play tournaments, you may have more than one game on a given day. Also, I have run into situations where a game has to be rescheduled, resulting in more than one game in a day. Just a thought...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you should have a GamePlayers table that associates your Players table with your Games table.  You could store a 'present' or 'not-present' flag, or you could just populate the GamePlayers table when they are present, which would mean not wasting space.   Ie, if a player does not have an entry in the GamePlayers table, then you already know they weren't present.  I assume most of the stats would be on an individual level and on a per-game basis, so they would likely reside in the GamePlayers table as well, and you'd likely have Team level stats that are either kept separately or calculated by aggregating results from the GamePlayers table.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys! That's what I thought I would have to do, just wanted to see if I was missing something. Everyone seems to be on the same page with this so I picked this answer. Thanks again!